# Pre Select Year in Angular JS Date Picker in Year format

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've a date picker and set the mode to Year to choose an year. I've year values like 2016, 1994 etc. 
If I set these values in ng-model of that date picker input, **it throws the error & shows wrong year.**

Also, I want only the Year value when the **Year Selected.**

JS code :

```
$scope.open = function() {
      $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.yu = 2200;

  $scope.dateOptionsForYear={
    showWeeks: false,
    datepickerMode : 'year',
    minMode : 'year'  
  }
```

HTML :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Year" ng-model="yu" uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy"
   ng-click="open()"
   class="form-control" 
   is-open="opened" show-button-bar="false"
   datepicker-options="dateOptionsForYear"/>
```

I've set up a Plunker. Here's the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/caJGGBcLck32TMqOyenD?p=preview)!

Answer (score 1):

make the code to

```
$scope.yu = 2200;
```

to

```
$scope.yu = new Date("1994");
```